# type "" is not a member of package controllers play framework

Tags: playframework

I'm following a tutorial of the Play Framework but I occurred in a problem, I wrote this object:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._

object Tickets extends Controller {
  def ticketsAvailable = Action { request =>
    val availableTickets = 1000
    Ok(availableTickets.toString)
  }
}
```

and then add the routes:

```
GET     /tickets/available/         controllers.Tickets.ticketsAvailable
```

but when I compiled and received this error:

> type Tickets is not a member of package controllers

Anyone can help me with an example of how i can fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Change your `object` to a `class`, ie.

```
class Tickets extends Controller {
```

And of course `Tickets.scala` should be packaged under `app/controllers`.

Comment: Hi Nio. Your answer has a few months but it solves my issue as well. Can you explain me why modifying object to class solve this particular problem?

Comment: ohe, since version 2.4 Play (by default) adopts the use of Dependency Injection (Google Guice) out of the box in it's bid to remove global state from the framework. [Read this in the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#Dependency-Injection) - it explains things a bit more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code from Object ApplictionController extends Controller{} to Class ApplicationController extends Controller{} and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem after introducing a compilation error into a class the controller uses.

Specifically, I didn't finish a method call. Instead of doing `object.someMethod()`, I wrote `object.`.

So, the `type is not a member...` error could mean that one or more of your controllers have trouble instantiating.